# I am trying to do probabilistic matching using R package fastLink, but I am receiving an error message I cannot decode

Tags: r, probabilistic-programming

I was trying to connect information about same patients that are potentially registered in two different databases
This is the error message I am receiving

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘ade4’

Comment: Try reinstalling fastLink `install.packages("fastLink", dependencies = TRUE)`.